# Differentiable Structure of Atlas and its Relationship to Topology

Tags: differential-topology

If two atlases have the same differential structure (they're both $C^r$) do they necessarily have the same topology?  My thought is, since an atlas induces both the differentiable structure and the topology then the answer to my question might be yes.

Comment: A smooth map is necessarily continuous, so a smooth map with smooth inverse is a continuous map with continuous inverse. Diffeomorphisms are homeomorphisms, too.

Comment: If you're asking whether a _set_ can have two different $C^r$ compatible atlases that induce different topologies, then the answer is certainly yes. Since every (nonempty) positive-dimensional manifold has the cardinality of $\mathbb R$, we can define one $C^r$-compatible atlas on $\mathbb R$ that induces the usual topology on $\mathbb R$, and another that induces the topology of, say, $S^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because there are smooth manifolds (i.e., both $C^{\infty}$) that are homoemorphic but not diffeomorphic. The classic reference for this is Milnor's paper on differentiable structures on the 7-sphere, ca 1960.

Comment: The question appears to be asking the converse.

Comment: Now that you mention it, it *does* seem to be asking that, and your answer and Jack Lee's comment both answer that nicely. On the other hand, the OP seems to have selected my answer, so perhaps my misunderstanding matched OP's mis-statement or something. :)  I'm leaving it here because someone else might arrive here when trying to ask a similar question.

Comment: Certainly I've no objection to more people learning about Milnor's beautiful paper :)